# Why can't a HashSet or LinkedList of Integers converted to int[]?

Tags: java, arrays, generics, types, integer

```
    public static String duplicate(int[] numbers){
        Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
        Set<Integer> duplicates = new HashSet<>();

        for (int num : numbers){
            if (set.contains(num)) {
                duplicates.add(num);
            } else {
                set.add(num);
            }
        }
        int[] ans = duplicates.toArray();
        return ans.sort().toString();
    }
```

Eclipse says "Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object[] to int[]" for the line `int[] ans = duplicates.toArray();`

Why not? I tried LinkedList and ArrayList also. The HashSet() uses the  type, while does the .toArray() function think the return will be Object[]?

Answer (score 3):

[Set.toArray](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#toArray--) returns `Object` array

> Object[] toArray()

You can convert `Set<Integer>` to `Integer` array

```
Integer[] i = duplicates.toArray(Integer[]::new);
```

Or you can use java-8 `stream` by iterating the `Set`

```
int[] arr = duplicates.stream().mapToInt(i->i).toArray();  // or mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
```

**Note :** On other side your method return type is `String` and `arr.toString()` returns string representation of an object like `[I@edf4efb`  [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--)

> Returns a string representation of the object. In general, the toString method returns a string that "textually represents" this object. The result should be a concise but informative representation that is easy for a person to read

Answer (score 0):

int[] is a primitive data type in Java and it's an object and not a Class.
If you need to convert to an Object[] Class you can use the Wrapper classes which is Integer[] since they inherit from Object class.

More about wrapper classes in Java : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/wrapper-classes-java/

Comment: Hmm, `int[]` is not a primitive type, it's an _array_ of a primitive type. The array itself is an object and has a class: `Class<int[]>`.